executing an mysql update statement held on a table
I am trying to execute update statements that are stored on a table. I must first select the row that the update statement is on to get the statement, then I need to execute that update statement.
I am attempting to use the prepared and execute sequence, but I am only able to execute the first statement. When I try to nest that statement pair into a subquery it fails.
This works...
PREPARE prepared_stmt1 from "SELECT FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID = 12345"; EXECUTE prepared_stmt1;
It returns data like:
UPDATE SECOND_TABLE SET THIS = THAT
I need to be able to execute that update statement. So I tried a number of different combinations of this:
PREPARE prepared_stmt2 from (PREPARE prepared_stmt1 from "SELECT UPDATE_STATEMENT FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID = 12345"; EXECUTE prepared_stmt1); EXECUTE prepared_stmt2;

'It returns data like' - no it doesn't , nothing is selected. And any reason why are you using dynamic sql to select from first_table?

Push the result of the select from first_table into a user defined variable and execute that for example
drop table if exists t,T1;
create table t(ID INT,STMT VARCHAR(200));

CREATE TABLE T1 (THIS INT,THAT INT);

insert into t values (12345,'update t1 set this = that;');
insert into t1 values (null,1);

SELECT stmt into @stmt  FROM t WHERE ID = 12345;

select @stmt;

PREPARE prepared_stmt1 from @stmt; 
EXECUTE prepared_stmt1;
deallocate prepare prepared_stmt1;

select * from t1;

If you must use a prepared statement to get the update statement then include the udv in the select and run a second prepared statement to execute it.
PREPARE prepared_stmt1 from "SELECT stmt into @stmt FROM t WHERE ID = 12345"; 
EXECUTE prepared_stmt1;
deallocate prepare prepared_stmt1;

select @stmt;

PREPARE prepared_stmt1 from @stmt; 
EXECUTE prepared_stmt1;
deallocate prepare prepared_stmt1;

select * from t1;

